# Adding a php script to move orders to new order status : Magento 1

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to write a php script to batch orders from the order status "complete" to the order status "Hold-Monogram Order". This script will run when you go to a specific URL.

Magento 1 v. 1.14.2.2

The order status "Hold-Monogram Order" is assigned to the "Complete" order state.

Below is the php script I have written, but am super new to writing scripts so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $status = $order->getStatus();
        $message = 'complete';
        if ($status == 'complete'){
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, 'hold_monogram_order', $message)->save();
            echo "complete";
        }
?>
```

When I go the URL currently to run the script, I get a blank white page, which usually means the script is running (I think), it just may not be correctly worded, so i would also like to return a message that says "script complete".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you specify, are you running script from magento root or any other place?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running script from magento root, then do code like this.

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();

try 
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $status = $order->getStatus();
    $message = 'complete';
    if ($status == 'complete') {
       $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, 'hold_monogram_order', $message)->save();
       echo "complete";
    }
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: this is great. thanks. unfortunately it didnt move any orders from Complete to Hold-Monogram Order but it didnt error out.

Comment: i am running it from the root folder. sorry

Comment: Unless you edited your answer, I did try it and it didn’t work. Can’t figure out why.